# How to display images from an array in react JS

Tags: reactjs, arrays, image

I have a js array with picture path in it, and I want to display it

I am trying to display an image from an array in react JS but it's not working. I tried to import it as a variable in my array but t's the same. The path is good I checked it.

:

```
export const memberList = [
  {
    id: '001',
    picture: '../assets/killian.png',
    name: 'Killian Barbarin',
    poste: 'CEO',
    desc: "Après avoir découvert l'investissement en bourse, Killian a décidé de trouver un outil qui correspondait à ses attentes. C'est comme ça qu'algobourse est né. Il s'occupe aussi du développement de l'application sur ses heures perdues.",
  },
  {
    id: '002',
    picture: '../assets/audrey.png',
    name: 'Audrey Rasolonjatovo',
    poste: 'Développeuse',
    desc: "Passionée par l'informatique, Audrey à choisi ce domaine dans le but d'aider et de simplifier le quotidien. C'est d'ailleurs ce qu'elle fait à algobourse où elle s'occupe du développement de l'application mobile et ce pour la durée de son alternance.",
  },
]
```

And I use a map and a componant to display it but it doesn't work.

This is the map :

```
        <div className="team__list">
          {memberList.map((ppl, index) => (
            <TeamMember
              key={ppl.id}
              img={ppl.picture}
              name={ppl.name}
              rule={ppl.poste}
              desc={ppl.desc}
            />
          ))}
```

And this is the composant I use to display all my data :

```
import './index.scss'

export default function TeamMember({ img, name, rule, desc }) {
  return (
    <div className="member">
      <div className="user">
        <img src={img} alt="" />
        <p className="user__name">{name}</p>
        <p className="user__rule">{rule}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="desc">
        <p>{desc}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

All the other variables are display correctly but the image is not display.

This is the organisation of my folders :
[image]

If someOne have any solution ?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I don't understand what i do wrong, I'm a beginner in react JS

Comment: What part of the linked article are you not understanding?

Comment: Ok, I didn't get it first, I thought i had to modify my code

Comment: @xXx_Ninj4_Kill3r_xXx that's an issue relating to how you are accessing `assets` and without a context of where your "assets" are in relation to where your `TeamMember` component lies then we have no chance of guessing what's the relative path. You may as well test that `img` is working by providing it a hardcoded URL then fix your wrong paths. Another suggestion I can give you is to have your images inside the `public` folder of your project and then an `images` folder and to access those images the path would be `images/killian.png`, etc. NOTE: you shouldn't store CSS or JS inside `public`.

Comment: I had all my folder organisation but yes, in data the path is somthing like '../assets/img.png' and in my componant it's '../../assets/img.png'

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found the solution, I have to import my images like that  `import image from '../assets/image.png'`, I don't know why but i can't just put my src in a string